# How do I add a second 'single product' in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn1sv.png)

How do I add a second single product page?  Is it even possible?

Specifically, I have about 600 products or so, and I want to add repairs as well.  I want to use the repairs page as a single product page, as well as using the old single product page for the shop page.

Just wondering if its possible to do?

I've tried pretty much everything I can find.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the only way to do fix this, by manually specifying the repair products to link to a repairs page?  Or can I just add a second single product page and then link them that way?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to implement this via this hook, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/ You have to check if you are dealing with a product, and if so if it is one of your "repair" products - and then specify the alternative template file. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/ should help to query what type of post you are dealing with inside the hook callback function.

Comment: Was thinking that myself.  Cheers.  So there's no way you can create 2 different single product pages I assume?